# MongoDB aggregation project string to ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am attempting to convert a  hexadecimal string to its equivalent ObjectID in an aggregation query. I tried two different methods:

```
db.omvas.aggregate([
    {$project:{
        EID:{$let: {
               vars: {
                  id:  "$EID"
               },
               in: ObjectId("$$id")
            }},
        }
    },
    {$group:{
        _id:"$EID"
        }
    }
]);
```

and

```
db.omvas.aggregate([
    {$project:{
        EID: ObjectId("$EID")
        }
    },
    {$group:{
        _id:"$EID"
        }
    }
]);
```

I keep getting the error "Error: invalid object id: length" using either method. I tested adding a literal string in place of the aggregation variable and I get a result with a proper ObjectID. It seems that the string value is not being passed through to Mongo's ObjectId function but rather the variable name is being passed as a literal string.

Anyone have any idea if what I am trying to accomplish is possible? Is there some magic I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ObjectId` is a constructor for ObjectIds in the shell. When you write something like

```
"EID" : { "$let" : {
           "vars" : { "id" :  "$EID" },
           "in" : ObjectId("$$id")
        } }
```

the mongo shell evaluates `ObjectId("$$id")` before sending the aggregation request. It's just like if you called a function in Javascript like

```
var x = 2
var y = 4
f(x + y) // f(6)
```

What you need is an aggregation operator to convert a string into an ObjectId. Unfortunately, no such function exists, as of MongoDB 2.6. Why do you need to convert the string? What are you going to do with it? Maybe there is a way around the lack of a conversion operator in aggregation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. This particular query is just one stage in a reporting workflow. The ObjectId was necessary as it is being used by queries farther down the pipeline. I'm rethinking how they work now and think I have a better way of executing them.

Comment: In my case I want to do a `$lookup` where the local field is a String representation of an `ObjectId` and the foreign field is an actual `ObjectId`.   Any idea if this is possible w/ MongoDB 3.2?

Comment: A way around it would be to write a script that adds a new field containing the id as an ObjectId to the documents in the collection. Then do the $lookup using the new field.

Comment: Can We convert string into objectID with js ?
My aggregation pipeline is dynamic and need to pass ID as a parameter in pipeline so after convert that string into objectId, I have to pass it as function parameter.

Answer (score 13):

You can use shorthand [`$toObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) in mongo version 4.0.

Something like

```
db.omvas.aggregate([
   {"$project":{"EID":{"$toObjectId":"$EID"}}
])
```

Comment: what if the EID contains some invalid objectid