# Mongodb group by and sum and get media with Map

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have these collections in my database:

**Items:**

```
{ "IdUser" : "1", "IdItem" : "1" },
{ "IdUser" : "1", "IdItem" : "2" },
{ "IdUser" : "1", "IdItem" : "3" },
{ "IdUser" : "2", "IdItem" : "4" },
{ "IdUser" : "2", "IdItem" : "5" },
{ "IdUser" : "4", "IdItem" : "6" },
{ "IdUser" : "5", "IdItem" : "7" }
```

**Users**

```
{ "_id" : "1", "DateRegister" : ISODate("2016-03-29T22:00:38.764+0000") },
{ "_id" : "2", "DateRegister" : ISODate("2014-03-29T22:00:38.764+0000") },
{ "_id" : "2", "DateRegister" : ISODate("2015-02-29T22:00:38.764+0000") },
{ "_id" : "4", "DateRegister" : ISODate("2013-01-29T22:00:38.764+0000") },
{ "_id" : "5", "DateRegister" : ISODate("2016-04-29T22:00:38.764+0000") }
```

How can I obtain this result but FILTERED with users registered after **2015**:

> Users with one item: 2
>
> Users with two items: 1
>
> Users with three items: 1

I have tried with that, but I don't know how to filter... Thanks!

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$IdUser",
            "count": { 
                "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$gt": [ "$IdItem", null ] }, 1, 0 ] } 
            }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$count",
            "users": { "$push": "$_id" }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "number_of_items": "$_id", 
            "number_of_users": { "$size": "$users" } 
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to utilize the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator to perform a join of the items collection with the users collection and then do a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** filter on the `DateRegistered` field before piping the main grouping operations.

Following this example + the links herein to the documentation will give you an idea:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "IdUser",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "user"
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "user.DateRegister": { "$gt": new Date(2015, 11, 31) } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$IdUser",
            "count": { 
                "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$gt": [ "$IdItem", null ] }, 1, 0 ] } 
            }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$count",
            "users": { "$push": "$_id" }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "number_of_items": "$_id", 
            "number_of_users": { "$size": "$users" } 
        }
    }
])
```

---

In the event that your MongoDB server does not support the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator, you will then need a workaround where you split the operations on the different collections i.e.

- get a list of user id's that match the given date range criteria, this could be done with the **[`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** method on the users collection with the date query option.
- use that list in the items collection aggregation pipeline within the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator initial step.

The following demonstrates this:

```
// use distinct to get the user id's list
var userIds = db.users.distinct("_id", { "DateRegister": { "$gt": new Date(2015, 11, 31) } })

// perform your aggregation with a filtered collection using the list from the above operations
db.items.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "IdUser": { "$in": userIds } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$IdUser",
            "count": { 
                "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$gt": [ "$IdItem", null ] }, 1, 0 ] } 
            }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$count",
            "users": { "$push": "$_id" }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "number_of_items": "$_id", 
            "number_of_users": { "$size": "$users" } 
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much ;) It works fine... one comment, imaging that IdUser is a ObjectId is collection users and a string in Items collection, how can I parse that?

Comment: Seems a bit counter-intuitive to me; why would you save the ids as strings in the items collection instead of just saving the refs as `ObjectId`s? Anyhow, to parse the strings you would need an additional `$project` operator step before the `$lookup` pipeline to do the parsing: follow this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27571758/122005) for guidance.