# Mongodb $lookup Not working with _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

wend try with this query, return the lookup is empty

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
    {$match: {typet:'Req'}},
    {$project: {incharge:1}},
    {$lookup:{
            from: "users",
            localField: "incharge", //this is the _id user from tests
            foreignField: "_id", //this is the _id from users
            as: "user"
    }}
])
```

return json

```
  [
    {
        "_id": "57565d2e45bd27b012fc4db9",
        "incharge": "549e0bb67371ecc804ad23ef",
        "user": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "57565d2045bd27b012fc4cbb",
        "incharge": "549e0bb67371ecc804ad21ef",
        "user": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "57565d2245bd27b012fc4cc7",
        "incharge": "549e0bb67371ecc804ad24ef",
        "user": []
    }
]
```

i try with this post but nothing happend 
[MongoDB aggregation project string to ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570698/mongodb-aggregation-project-string-to-objectid)
and with this 
[MongoDB $lookup with _id as a foreignField in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518571/mongodb-lookup-with-id-as-a-foreignfield-in-php)

**UPDATE**

this is the Document "users"

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("549e0bb67371ecc804ad24ef"),
        "displayname" : "Jhon S."
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("549e0bb67371ecc804ad21ef"),
        "displayname" : "George F."
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("549e0bb67371ecc804ad23ef"),
        "displayname" : "Franc D."
    }
```

Comment: please post document examples as this will help us to help you :-)

Comment: Thanks Man Add document users

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I finaly found the solution, is a problem with my Schema in mongoose with the ObjectId

I change this

```
var Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    incharge: { type: String, required: true},
});
```

with this

```
var Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    incharge: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, required: true},
});
```

and is working

Comment: my both Id are mongoose object id but still I am getting empty array

Comment: it returns empty array

Comment: can you please also tell how to do this on Shell

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this! I couldn't for the life of me work it out. Good job man!

Answer (score 20):

First, assert that the type of the `incharge` field is  `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. If you still get an empty array back it might be because you are using the **schema** name you declared in NodeJS instead of the **collection** name used by MongoDB.

Example from a `UserSchema` file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  incharge: { 
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    required: true
  },
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
module.exports = User
```

The model above is named `User` by mongoose but the corresponding collection in mongoDB is named `users`. The resulting `$lookup` is written as:

```
$lookup:{
  from: "users",           // name of mongoDB collection, NOT mongoose model
  localField: "incharge",  // referenced users _id in the tests collection
  foreignField: "_id",     // _id from users
  as: "user"               // output array in returned object
}
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: One s changed things for me

Answer (score 15):

Comparing a `string` with an `ObjectId` doesn't throw an error, rather sends an empty array in the aggregated output document. So you need to make sure that you have converted the `string` object id to mongodb's `ObjectId`:

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
    {$match: {typet:'Req'}},
    {$set: {incharge: {$toObjectId: "$incharge"} }}, // keep the whole document structure, but replace `incharge` into ObjectId
    {$lookup:{
            from: "users",
            localField: "incharge", //this is the _id user from tests
            foreignField: "_id", //this is the _id from users
            as: "user"
    }}
])
```

Comment: worked like a charm for me. I can confirm that this works

Answer (score 8):

You just have to use `"_id.str"` and work will be done.

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
{$match: {typet:'Req'}},
{$project: {incharge:1}},
{$lookup:{
        from: "users",
        localField: "incharge", //this is the _id user from tests
        foreignField: "_id.str", //this is the _id from users
        as: "user"
}}
```

])

Works fine for me.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, but I put a little diferent. 
 foreignField: "_id".toString(), //this is the _id from users

Answer (score 6):

Your lookup Query is correct. But it is trying to compare a string type (incharge) with ObjectId (_id). Convert the string to ObjectId as shown below. It works for me.

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
{$match: {typet:'Req'}},
{$project: {
   incharge:{
     $toObjectId:"$incharge"
   }
},
{$lookup:{
        from: "users",
        localField: "incharge", //this is the _id user from tests
        foreignField: "_id", //this is the _id from users
        as: "user"
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

try changing type of incharge which is string to ObjectId in aggregate function
like this

```
{ 
    $project : {
        incharge : {
            $toObjectId : "$incharge"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your lookup query is perfect, but the problem is you are storing **incharge** as string into the db, whereas the _id : ObjectId('theID') is an Object and not just string and you cannot compare a `string` (' ') with an `object` ({ }). So, the best way is to store the **incharge** key as an object(**mongoose.Schema.ObjectId**) and not as string in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored key in string you can use $addFields (aggregation) to convert the key into objectId

```
{
        "$addFields": {
            incharge: {
                "$toObjectId": "$incharge"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
{
  from: 'categories',
  let: { cid: { $toObjectId: '$category_id' } },
  pipeline: [
    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$cid'] } } },
  ],
  as: 'category_data'
}
```

[$lookup foreignField is ObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/lookup-foreignfield-is-objectid/126872/7?u=liangchaoshun_n_a)