# Why my mongdb $lookup does not work?

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I'm trying to make a $lookup between two collections, on _id field. It always return me an empty object.

It's the exact same problem as [Mongodb $lookup Not working with _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705517/mongodb-lookup-not-working-with-id)

But I already implemented his solution. It know about type coertion and my id fields are the exact same type: `Schema.ObjectId`

Here's my session collection:

```
var sessionSchema = new Schema({
    user        : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    startDate   : Date,
    endDate     : Date
});
```

and the request:

```
db.sessions.aggregate([{$project: {user:1}}, { $lookup : { from: "User", localField: "user", foreignField: "_id", as: "u" }} ]);
```

and the results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5697d6c810ad24b91b130df2"), "user" : ObjectId("5697d6c210ad24b91b130df1"), "u" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5697d6d810ad24b91b130df3"), "user" : ObjectId("5697d6c210ad24b91b130df1"), "u" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5697d70410ad24b91b130df4"), "user" : ObjectId("5697d6c210ad24b91b130df1"), "u" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5697d71310ad24b91b130df5"), "user" : ObjectId("5697d6c210ad24b91b130df1"), "u" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5697d71c10ad24b91b130df6"), "user" : ObjectId("5697d6c210ad24b91b130df1"), "u" : [ ] }
```

I don't think it could be useful to mention my User collection, because only only interesting field is `_id`

There must be missing an obvious thing, and because i'm not a mongo expert, I can't find it.

Comment: Where's "me" field from?

Comment: what "me" field? ;)  sorry, a typo. This is the field created by lookup : `u`

Comment: ok. Are you sure your User collection is spelled as "User" and not "user"? Because ''sessions" collection is in lower case

Comment: I tried `user` too, of course

Comment: Oh, I found it! It was `users`, with plural mode! The mongodb documentation do not mention it, and their "inventory" example is not plural (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: )) it's called "copy/paste" mistake

Comment: Oh, in fact I don't have to blame mongodb documentation. The plural mode comes from `Mongoose`. It automatically creates collections with the object plural mode :/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't mention i'm using Mongoose.

When you're creating a collection, Mongoose automagically create the relative table [with the plural mode.](https://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=mongodb%20pluralization&oq=mongodb%20plura&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5991j0j7)

So my mistake was to reference `from: "user"` instead of `from: "users"`